# Parsing a json file - Python

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, parsing

I have a Json file from which I want to extract particular data. Below is the JSON file:

```
{
    "results": [ {
        "alternatives": [ {
            "word_confidence": [
                [ "Ryan", 0.335 ],
                [ "how's", 0.589 ],
                [ "the", 1.0 ],
                [ "weather", 1.0 ],
                [ "in", 1.0 ],
                [ "New", 1.0],
                [ "York", 0.989 ],
                [ "today", 0.987 ]
            ],
            "confidence": 0.795,
            "transcript": "Ryan how's the weather in New York today "
        } ],
        "final": true
    } ],
    "result_index": 0
}
```

Using python, how can I parse this file and get extract "transcript"?

Comment: `import json; data=json.loads(json_string)`

Comment: @stephen
I used
   ' import json; data = json.loads(json_string)'
which returns
    '{u'results': [{u'alternatives': [{u'transcript': u"Ryan how's the weather in New York today ", u'confidence': 0.795, u'word_confidence': [[u'Ryan', 0.335], [u"how's", 0.589], [u'the', 1.0], [u'weather', 1.0], [u'in', 1.0], [u'New', 1.0], [u'York', 0.989], [u'today', 0.987]]}], u'final': True}], u'result_index': 0}'

now I have to extract the data for key value "transcript".. how to do this

Comment: Found solution for this 
    data = json.loads(json_data)
    text_data = data["results"][0]["alternatives"][0]["transcript"]

Answer (score 2):

To convert the `json` string to a dict, use `json.loads()`.  Then to get the transcript, just reference into the `dict`, like:

**Code:**

```
import json
data = json.loads(json_string)
transcript = data['results'][0]['alternatives'][0]['transcript']
```

**Test Data:**

```
json_string = """
{
    "results": [ {
        "alternatives": [ {
            "word_confidence": [
                [ "Ryan", 0.335 ],
                [ "how's", 0.589 ],
                [ "the", 1.0 ],
                [ "weather", 1.0 ],
                [ "in", 1.0 ],
                [ "New", 1.0],
                [ "York", 0.989 ],
                [ "today", 0.987 ]
            ],
            "confidence": 0.795,
            "transcript": "Ryan how's the weather in New York today "
        } ],
        "final": true
    } ],
    "result_index": 0
}
"""
```